# ASP.NET Application Deploy on SharePoint Online

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, sharepoint

Is it possible to deploy a asp.net web application on SharePoint online. If possible, please tell me the steps how can i make this happen.

asp.net application is on latest .net framework and visual studio 2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately - no. It is not possible to host any kind of server-side code directly in SharePoint Online. SharePoint Online doesn't expose or give access to any IIS settings of the underlying infrastructure - everything for better security and performance of the whole service.

You can, however, connect externally hosted web applications to SharePoint using so-called Provider-hosted apps. You can deploy them in (for example) Microsoft Azure and then connect them to SharePoint as if they were a part of the same cloud solution. You may find this article helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-started-creating-provider-hosted-sharepoint-add-ins